# Using VectorDrawable in layout showing Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute issue

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-build, android-vectordrawable

As per the new release of Android studio tools build version `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'` am using VectorDrawable in my layout as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_txt"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

And in drawable folder generated VectorDrawable as follows:

**ic_arrow_right_16dp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M8.59,16.34l4.58,-4.59 -4.58,-4.59L10,5.75l6,6 -6,6z"/>
</vector>
```

**Issue I am facing**

Everything works up to the above steps. But once if i try to build the project I am getting error stating as follows

```
Error:(7) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Since I am using VectorDrawable for the first time in my project I really don't know where I am committing mistake and also confused to use which part of gradle build to make use of VectorDrawable's. Any help and solutions will be very helpful me. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** Currently my `buildToolsVersion` is `"23.0.1"`

Answer (score 1):

**"Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute"** =>

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Seems to be the duplicate ;)

Answer (score 0):

*You are give double Namespace in your xml file*

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Remove 1 Namespace from Your TextView